# Parse SDK iOS Analytics

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am working with Parse SDK in my iOS Application. I have integrated Parse Facebook SDK with my Application. I just want to do an analytics based on Users not overall count like we can give read count or something. (e.g) I want to do know the current user's access count of modules which I am having in my application and overall How many users have visited the particular module in certian period of time.Please help me out on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `[PFAnalytics trackEvent: dimensions:]` call.  This allows you to track an event with a particular name as an NSString and provide dimensions as an NSDictionary.

Here's an example of what you could put in the loading code for each module:

```
NSDictionary *dimensions = @{
  // Define the user via whatever unique ID you use
  @"user": userId,
  // Define the name of the module that is being loaded
  @"module": @"moduleName",
};
// Send the dimensions to Parse along with the 'search' event
[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"moduleLoad" dimensions:dimensions];
```

To get a total number of events, you will need to use the Parse.com dashboard. You may also need to download the events log and sum it via Excel.

Also, if you are looking for analytics tracking that is more robust at the user-level, I recommend http://www.mixpanel.com